# WSO2 EMM: A way to expose API for a native app building?

Tags: wso2

I am looking into WSO2 EMM and can't figure one thing: is there a way to expose its API to build a native application store for iPhone? Somewhat a set of basic functions will do:

- Authentication
- List of applications
- Search for application
- Install & Uninstall an application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. All the functions in EMM are exposed as APIs. You better look at the scripts at `wso2emm-1.1.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\emm\api` to get an idea on the APIs in EMM. You can find the endpoints inside those js filese. Also please note that this app is written using [JaggeryJS](http://jaggeryjs.org/). For the authentication you may look at SAML sso which has been used in EMM. For this you could use a modal dialog to load the SSO page or else you may modify it to support OAuth as [follows](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/07/sso-for-native-mobile-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/).